# Python 3 multiprocessing only using one core with 4 threads open

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm writing a simple prime number calculator, and I'm trying to make it as fast as possible. I have been looking into `multiprocessing` in python, and everywhere I look it seems as though opening 4 processes will launch 4 threads... which makes sense. However, when running the following code, I only get 1 process (in top/Activity Monitor (Mac)/etc.) even if 4 processes are open. I have set `primesPerThread` to 500 so that the processes will last longer before finishing, so that I can look for them (in top/etc). However, I only see one Python process using about 100% CPU. Is there something I'm not understanding/using in `multiprocessing`? Here's what I've got so far:

```
import multiprocessing
import math
import os
import time

def mod(numerator, denominator):
    result = numerator % denominator
    return result

def checkPrimes(low, high):
    global primes
    reult = 0
    curPrime = low
    notPrime = False

    for i in range(low, high):
        notPrime = False
        for j in range(int(math.floor(math.sqrt(len(primes))))):
            result = mod(curPrime, primes[j])
            if result == 0:
                notPrime = True
                break
        if not notPrime:
            primes.append(curPrime)
        curPrime += 1

cores = 4
primes = [2,3]
curPrime = 4
result = 0
notPrime = False
primesPerThread = 500
numPrimes = 0
prevNumPrimes = 0

processes = []

while len(primes) < 1000000:
    for c in range(0, cores):
        low = curPrime
        high = curPrime + primesPerThread
        process = multiprocessing.Process(target=checkPrimes(low, high))
        process.start()
        processes.append(process)
        curPrime += primesPerThread
    for process in processes:
        process.join()
    prevNumPrimes = numPrimes
    numPrimes = len(primes)
    print(len(primes))
    # for i in range(numPrimes - prevNumPrimes, 0, -1):
    #     os.popen("echo " + str(primes[len(primes) - i]) + " >> primes.txt")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiprocessing is not threads! As the name implies, it uses different processes instead of threads. So using a global variable will not work because it is not shared between processes.

Using a list comprehension is often prefreable to a for-loop, because it is faster. Consider this;

```
In [1]: import math

In [2]: %cpaste
Pasting code; enter '--' alone on the line to stop or use Ctrl-D.
:def prime_list(num):
:    if num < 3:
:        raise ValueError('this function only accepts arguments > 2')
:    # For numbers >2, only odd numbers are prime.
:    candidates = range(3, num+1, 2) 
:    # For an odd number c to be a prime, one must ensure that 
:    # c modulo all previous odd numbers (p) must be non-zero.
:    L = [c for c in candidates if all(c % p != 0 for p in
:         range(3, int(math.sqrt(c))+1, 2))]
:    # 2 is also a prime number.
:    return [2] + L
:--

In [3]: %timeit prime_list(100000)
1 loops, best of 3: 610 ms per loop

In [4]: rv =  prime_list(100000)

In [5]: len(rv)
Out[5]: 9592

In [6]: rv[:10]
Out[6]: [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29]

In [7]: rv[-10:]
Out[7]: [99877, 99881, 99901, 99907, 99923, 99929, 99961, 99971, 99989, 99991]
```

This algorithm takes only 0.6 seconds to find the primes in the first 100,000 numbers. Of course this time will climb rapidly when you make the list of numbers to search longer; you'll have to check all odd numbers up to √c.

```
In [8]: %timeit prime_list(1000000)
1 loops, best of 3: 12.7 s per loop
```

You could parallelize this by adding a minimum number from which to check to the `prime_list`, and then use the `map` method from the `multiprocessing.Pool` object to spread the work over multiple instances.

```
import math
import multiprocessing

def prime_list2(arg):
    start, num = arg # Unpack the tuple.
    if num < 3:
        raise ValueError('this function only accepts arguments > 2')
    if start < 3:
       start = 3
    candidates = range(start, num+1, 2)
    L = [c for c in candidates if all(c % p != 0 for p in
         range(3, int(math.sqrt(c))+1, 2))]
    if start < 3:
        L = [2] + L
    return L

data = [(n*100000+1, (n+1)*100000+1) for n in range(0,10)]
p = multiprocessing.Pool()
rv = p.map(prime_list2, data)
print('len(rv)=', len(rv))
for i, v in enumerate(rv):
    print('rv[{}][:10] ='.format(i), v[:10])
```

This gives:

```
len(rv)= 10
rv[0][:10] = [3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31]
rv[1][:10] = [100003, 100019, 100043, 100049, 100057, 100069, 100103, 100109, 100129, 100151]
rv[2][:10] = [200003, 200009, 200017, 200023, 200029, 200033, 200041, 200063, 200087, 200117]
rv[3][:10] = [300007, 300017, 300023, 300043, 300073, 300089, 300109, 300119, 300137, 300149]
rv[4][:10] = [400009, 400031, 400033, 400051, 400067, 400069, 400087, 400093, 400109, 400123]
rv[5][:10] = [500009, 500029, 500041, 500057, 500069, 500083, 500107, 500111, 500113, 500119]
rv[6][:10] = [600011, 600043, 600053, 600071, 600073, 600091, 600101, 600109, 600167, 600169]
rv[7][:10] = [700001, 700027, 700057, 700067, 700079, 700081, 700087, 700099, 700103, 700109]
rv[8][:10] = [800011, 800029, 800053, 800057, 800077, 800083, 800089, 800113, 800117, 800119]
rv[9][:10] = [900001, 900007, 900019, 900037, 900061, 900089, 900091, 900103, 900121, 900139]
```

Comment: So the reason mine wasn't working was because of the global variable? If so, could I return an array? And what's the best way to capture what is returned from a function when it is called through multiprocessing? Sorry, I'm pretty new to multithreading in python (obviously).

Comment: @TheMacMini09: Spreading calculations over multiple processes and returning data to the original process is what a `Pool` is for.

Comment: Ah I see now. I had somehow missed that bit of code at the end. Thanks!

Comment: Ok, I've managed to get multiple processes working on multiple cores simultaneously, but it now takes 4 times longer than the normal code to process! [Here is the new code](http://pastebin.com/vYES0pu0). When running with `cores` overridden to 1 and `high` set to 10000 (will generate primes up to 100000), it takes 0.959 seconds to complete (not printing anything). When running `checkPrimes( (3,100000, primes) )` it takes only 0.283 seconds. Am I handling processes inefficiently? Thanks again!